# Проблема при получении списка папок и подпапок

Tags: php

Не поскажите почему этот код выходит в бесконечную рекурсию, из за чего сжирает всю оперативную память и перестаёт работать?

```
public function getFiles($dir, $array = []){
    if(is_dir($dir)){
        $directory = scandir($dir);
        foreach($directory as $file){
            if($file != "." and $file != ".."){
                if(is_dir($dir."/".$file)){
                    $directory_files = $this->getFiles($dir."/".$file, $array);
                    $array = array_merge($array, $directory_files);
                }
                $array[] = $dir."/".$file;
            }
        }
    }
    $array[] = $dir;
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Может папок много вложенных, кто знает

Comment: 96 файлов считается много? А array_merge служит для сложения путей из подпапки (повторный вызов этой функции).

Comment: Для начала, можно было бы массив объявлять в функции через амперсанд `&$array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поправил ваш код, так, должно работать(*не тестировалось*).

```
 function getFiles($dir) {

   $result = array();    
   $directory = scandir($dir);
   foreach ($directory as $key => $file)
   {
      if (!in_array($file,array(".","..")))
      {
         if (is_dir($dir."/".$file))
            $result[$file] = getFiles($dir."/".$value);
         else
            $result[] = $file;
      }
   }      
   return $result;
} 

var_dump(getFiles("some_dir"));
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса будет признателен вам за развернутый экспертный комментарий поясняющий код.

Comment: Спасибо большое. В одном месте только ошибка, поправил. Теперь идеально!)